# Getting length of string in NASM with strlen call

Tags: c, linux, nasm

My aim is to do the following:

1) Write a nasm code that calculates the length of a string by calling strlen from C

2) Call this function in C to print the length of a supplied string

Nasm code:

```
    ;nasm -f elf32 getLength.asm -o getLength.o


segment .text
extern strlen
global getLength

getLength:
    push    ebp                 ;save the old base pointer value
    mov     ebp,esp             ;base pointer <- stack pointer

    mov     eax,[ebp+8]         ;first argument
    call    strlen              ; call our function to calculate the length of the string

    mov         edx, eax            ; our function leaves the result in EAX
    pop ebp
    ret
```

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int getLength(char *str);

int main(void)
{
    char str[256];
    int l;

    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%s" , str) ;
    //l = strlen(str);
    l = getLength(str);
    printf("The length is: %d\n", l);
    return 0;
}
```

I try to compile, link and run as follows:

1) nasm -f elf32 getLength.asm -o getLength.o

2) gcc -c length.c -o getLength.o -m32

3)gcc getLength.o getLength.o -o length -m32

The error I get:

```
getLength.o: In function `getLength':
getLength.asm:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `getLength'
getLength.o:getLength.asm:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib32/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from the error you get, it would seem you compiled the C file before the ASM file, not after as you described.

To complicate things, the resulting object files will have the same filename. Since you compiled the ASM file last, `getLength.o` is the compiled ASM file.

The result is that you're trying to link multiple functions named `getLength` (from the ASM file) and you don't have a `main` function to link at all.

You can fix it by using different names for the object files (e.g. `length.o` for the C file and `getLength.o` for the ASM file):

```
gcc -c length.c -o length.o -m32
nasm -f elf32 getLength.asm -o getLength.o
gcc length.o getLength.o -o length -m32
```

By the way, your `getLength` function appears to be incorrect:

1. You forgot to move the argument to `strlen` onto the stack. `push eax` before calling `strlen`.
2. You moved the return value from `eax` into `edx` after calling `strlen`. This shouldn't be necessary since `eax` will already have the correct value.
3. Because you need to `push eax`, you also need to restore the stack pointer after `strlen` returns. You can either use `add esp, 4` or `mov esp, ebp` to accomplish this, but it must be done before you `pop ebp`.

Comment: Yes. That did the compilation trick ! However, there appears to be some kind of an error in my NASM code becouse I get 0 as the result.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

You overwrite the `getLength.o` from NASM with `gcc -c length.c -o getLength.o -m32`. Just take another name for the output of GCC:

1. nasm -f elf32 getLength.asm -o getLength.o
2. gcc -c length.c -o **length.o** -m32
3. gcc length.o getLength.o -o length -m32

GCC is smart enough, that you can collapse step 2. and 3.:

2+3. gcc length.c getLength.o -o length -m32

You forgot to pass an argument to `strlen` and to clear the stack afterwards:

```
getLength:
    push    ebp                 ;save the old base pointer value
    mov     ebp,esp             ;base pointer <- stack pointer

    mov     eax,[ebp+8]         ;first argument
    push eax                    ; first argument onto the stack
    call    strlen              ; call our function to calculate the length of the string
    add esp, 4                  ; clear stack after C-call

    mov         edx, eax            ; our function leaves the result in EAX
    pop ebp
    ret
```

There are left some superfluous instructions. Please check, if you really need them.